# How to use GIN index with array column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
id uuid
ancestor_ids text[]
```

I need to perform a query to retrieve the rows where the first element in the ancestor_ids array is any of the input values. The query looks something like this:

```
select * from table where ancestor_ids[1] in ('multiple', 'input', 'values');
```

The query is working fine but I'd like to know if adding an index to the `ancestor_ids` column would improve the performance given the fact I'm not using any special operator. Is it possible to optimize the query at all? (table re-design is not an option)

Answer (score 2):

If it's always the first element, no need for a GIN index. A standard B-Tree will do:

```
create index on the_table ( (ancestor_ids[1]) );
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to create this index:
ERROR: syntax error at or near ")", is it possible to index specific array positions?

Comment: @iamdeit: I missed a closing `)` - see my edit

Comment: It worked! I didn't know it needed double parenthesis. Thanks!